# Empty return object with @jsonView

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got User class with privilege list (ManyToMany relationship). There are some views that I used too.

```
@Column(name = "privileges")
@JsonView(Views.Manage.class)
@NotNull
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_privileges",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Privilege> privileges;

public static class Views {
    private interface Auto extends Manage {
    }

    public interface Add extends Manage{
    }

    public interface Manage {
    }
}
```

And Privilege class :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "privilege")
public class Privilege {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @JsonView(Views.Auto.class)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @JsonView(Views.Manage.class)
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    @JsonView(Views.Manage.class)
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;

    public static class Views{
        private interface Auto extends Manage{
        }

        public interface Manage{
        }
    }

}
```

In controller

```
@GetMapping("/users")
@JsonView(User.Views.Manage.class)
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

This returned List of users but their privileges are empty objects. In console and db, I got everything as expected. Any suggestion what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the fetch type to eager (in ManyToMany)?

```
fetch = FetchType.EAGER
```

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: Do you have accessors (getter and setter) for privileges in User class?

Answer (score 0):

The privileges are lazy loaded. So if in the code you do user.getPrivileges().get(0) for example it will be loaded and it will have its properties setup. The problem is that when you serialize to JSON these are not populated yet (they haven't been used yet). That's how ORMs work - they keep a proxy to the object in relation instead of the actual object in order to reduce the unnecessary load. You can either set privilliges to FetchType=Eager if you will always need them or you can lazy load them before the json serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Its happened because I have separate views. One for User and one for Privilege. When I connect them to one view it works.

UPDATE:

When you want JsonView from another class, you don't need one view for all. JsonView can have array values (nested views). For example, my problem was solved with

```
    @Column(name = "name")
    @JsonView({Views.Manage.class, User.Views.Manage.class})
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
```